# Use a boolean value from a resource file directly in a JSP page?

Tags: jsp

I am doing a Spring MVC application. I have a config.properties on the classpath. In this file, I have the following:

```
some_indicator=true
```

How can I use this value directly in a JSP? Something that can be used through JSTL such as the following (just an idea):

```
<c:if test="${ some_indicator }">
....do something
</c:If>
```

### Update

config.properties is not made available through Spring's ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. It is  not a message file.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the value in your config.properties like it is a message

```
<fmt:message key="some_indicator" />
```

put the value inside a variable

```
<c:set var="testvar" value='<fmt:message key="key" />' />
```

and then use as you want.

```
<c:if test="${testvar}">
....do something
</c:if>
```

Comment: FAIfeo, config.properties is not a message file. It is not made available through Spring's ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: I think is the same thing (In Spring, you can use ResourceBundleMessageSource to resolve text messages from properties file, base on the selected locales). The point is you have to put your "key" in an attribute of Request (via backend or via JSTL ) to put inside an EL statement like <c:if test="${some_indicator}">.

Comment: I tested it. `<c:set var="testvar" value='<fmt:message key="key" />' />` does not assign any value to `testvar`